# Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined when singing apk github actions

Tags: android, github-actions

I only encounter this issue when I try to run the workflow on a self-hosted node. can anyone help ?

```
Run r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1 Preparing to sign key @ app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release with signing key Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

My workflow is configured like that:

```
name: Generate Release APK
           run: ./gradlew assembleRelease
name: Sign APK
           uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
           id: sign_app
           with:
                  releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release
                  signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
                  alias: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_ALIAS }}
                  keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
                  keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using env variables adding ANDROID_HOME like this :

```
- name: Sign APK with keystore
        uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
        id: sign_app
        with:
          releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release
          signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_BASE64 }}
          alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
          keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
          keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
        env:
          ANDROID_HOME: $HOME/Android/Sdk
```